# How do I process the configure file when cross-compiling with mingw?

Tags: mingw

I have a small open source program that builds with an autoconf configure script.

I ran configure I tried to compile with:

```
make CC="/opt/local/bin/i386-mingw32-g++"
```

That didn't work because the configure script found include files that were not available to the mingw system.

So then I tried:

```
./configure CC="/opt/local/bin/i386-mingw32-g++"
```

Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

./configure --host=i686-pc-mingw32

...which tells configure that you want to target a different platform. Provided your cross-compile environment is setup correctly i.e. you have an "i686-pc-mingw32-gcc" in your path, it should all just work.

Comment: Turns out that didn't work. The Mac mingw installation I found installs the executable as i686-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1. specifying '--host=i686-apple-darwin10' and '--host=i686-pc-mingw32' don't work.

Comment: Ah, but in addition to installing the compiler as i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 it also installed /usr/local/i386-mingw32-4.3.0/bin/i386-mingw32-gcc. Adding /usr/local/i386-mingw32-4.3.0/bin/ to my $PATH and running ./configure --host=i386-mingw32 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to work:

```
  MBIN=/opt/local/bin/
  PREFIX=/opt/local/i386-mingw32
  export CC=$MBIN/i386-mingw32-gcc
  export CXX=$MBIN/i386-mingw32-g++
  export RANLIB=$MBIN/i386-mingw32-ranlib
  export AR=$MBIN/i386-mingw32-ar
  export MINGWFLAGS="-mwin32 -mconsole -march=pentium4 "
  export CFLAGS="$MINGWFLAGS"
  export CXXFLAGS="$MINGWFLAGS"
  VARS="CC=$CC CXX=$CXX RANLIB=$RANLIB AR=$AR"
  make $VARS CFLAGS="$CFLAGS" CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"
```